# selecting a select list in jquery

Tags: jquery

There has to be something really simple that I am overlooking, but for some reason I cannot find any information about this and it keeps coming up so..

I am trying to select a select element in jquery. Right now I don't care about it's options, I just want the select element. If I have the following element:

```
<select id="testSelect"><option>1</option></select>
```

and I use jquery to select it:

```
var selectElement = $("#testSelect");
```

I get an array of all the options in the select list, but not the select element itself. What am I missing?

Comment: Need a bit more context here, that selector should get the select element itself...can you post what you're trying to do with it that isn't behaving correctly?

Comment: I just need the select element object so I can use it in javascript for styles, show/hide. Sorry to be vague, I didn't include that because all I care about right now is understanding why I can't get a select object back. I know there are other workarounds for this, but it's really bugging me. For example, $("#testSelect").style is undefined (expected), $("#testSelect")[0] gives the list of options and not the select. thanks!

Comment: There are jQuery ways to handle the styles, for example `$('#testSelect').is(':visible')` or to get the display: `$('#testSelect').css('display)`, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting it correctly.

`var selectElement = $("#testSelect");`

Remember though that selectElement is now a jQuery object not a DOM node. This allows you to use jQuery methods to manipulate it as follows:

`selectElement.css({'background-color':'red', 'border':'1px solid'});`

`selectElement.hide();`

`selectElement.show();`

If you wish to access the DOM node directly use the get method as outlined here: http://api.jquery.com/get/. So for example if you want to access the DOM nodes style property you would do it like this:

`$('#tl_query_season').get(0).style`

and get background-color like this:

`$('#tl_query_season').get(0).style.backgroundColor`

But if you're doing this you're missing out on all the great jQuery functionality.

See Also: http://api.jquery.com/css/ and http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/